# is task/application manager available in iphone?

Tags: iphone, task, taskmanager

Is there any functionality of a task manager in iphone like we have in windows? if so how to access it?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word… no. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can try SmartGTD app (www.smartgtd.com) based on GTD®. It's going to be launched in a couple of days for iPad and really soon iPhone version.

Comment: if not yet available, this doesn't answer the question - yet :-)